# Analytic solution for system of trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have two equations as follows:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(\Delta_{11}\cos(\alpha) + \Delta_{12})\cos(\theta) + (\Delta_{21}\cos(\alpha) + \Delta_{22})\sin(\theta) = \Delta_{31}\sin(\alpha) + \Delta_{32} \\ 
(\Omega_{11}\cos(\alpha) + \Omega_{12})\cos(\theta) + (\Omega_{21}\cos(\alpha) + \Omega_{22})\sin(\theta) = \Omega_{31}\sin(\alpha) + \Omega_{32} \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
where $\Delta_{i,j}$ and $\Omega_{i,j}$ are known scalar values.

I want to ask if there is any solution for $\theta$ and $\alpha$? Both are also scalars.

Thank you very much for your help!

---

**What I have tried so far:**

**1.** One possible solution is to convert sin, cos to half angle tan, but this leads to an 8th order polynomial. Would it be possible to solve this polynomial for $\alpha$ and $\theta$ though?

**2.** Another special case, is when both $Δ_{32}$ and $Ω_{32}$ are zeros. After eliminating sin(α), the equation reduces to a 4th order polynomial, then it is in closed form.

**3.** Does anyone think it would be possible to reduce the equations to a 4th order polynomial for the general case? (i.e. when $Δ_{32}$ and $Ω_{32}$ are not zeros).

Comment: One possible solution is to convert sin, cos to half angle tan, but this leads to an 8th order polynomial.

Comment: Another special case, is when both $\Delta_{32}$ and $\Omega_{32}$ are zeros. After eliminate $sin(\alpha)$, it reduces to a 4th order polynomial, then it is in closed form.

Comment: Anyone thought it would be possible to reduce the equations to a 4th order polynomial for the general case, i.e., $\Delta_{32}$ and $\Omega_{32}$ are not zeros.